# React native position absolute

Tags: react-native

I want to fix my `Image`. I use `position: 'absolute'`, in iOS it works fine, but in android the image disappear. This is my code:

```
<Image style={{width: width, zIndex: 0, position: 'absolute',  top: 0}}
  source={require('../assets/2piano.png')}
  resizeMode="contain"
/>
```

Please HELP!!!

Comment: Define what you mean by "fix my image".

Comment: Check out this guide about managing assets in RN.  I'll guess the error is in the path, but let me know if it doesn't help you. Maybe you need to link the asset in android via `react-native link.`

https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/react-native-tips-and-tricks-2-0-managing-static-assets-with-absolute-paths/

Comment: No is Linked, if I remove "position: absolute" It Works

Answer (score 0):

This will work on both Android and iOS. Since your image is from the local resources you should give it a `width:null` and `height:null` in order to apply your own dimensions on it.

```js
<View style={{width: 500, height:500}}>
  <Image style={{width: null, height:null, zIndex: 0, position: 'absolute',  top: 0, bottom:0, left:0, right:0}}
      source={require('../assets/2piano.png')}
      resizeMode="contain"
    />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

For style:

```
  twoPianoStyle: {
      position: 'absolute',
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
  }
```